# how to trigger error method on ajax form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a controller method like below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveDetails")
public @ResponseBody ReturnTO saveDetails(@RequestParam("invenStr") String invenStr) {
    ReturnTO returnTO=new ReturnTO();   
     try{
             /**save invenStr **/
             returnTO.setStatus(false);
     }catch(Exception e){
             returnTO.setStatus(true);
     }
    return returnTO;
}
```

Here ReturnTO is a class having a boolean status variable and getter/setter for it

My query is: can setting the status variable to **true** and returning it as response body as a result of an ajax call trigger the **error** method of the callback. If no, is there any way to map the status variable to the callback method.

My ajax call is below:

```
   $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : contextRoot + "saveDetails.htm",
        async : false,
        timeout : 5000,
        data : {
            invenStr : invenStr
        },
        success : function(data, textStatus) {

        },
        error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: your code has neither jquery nor ajax

Comment: updated question with ajax call

Answer (score 0):

jquery ajax error callbacks are invoked when a different http response than ok(200) is received. To trigger the error method of the callback you should return a different http response code than  ok.